# Property Or Field Not Initialized Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, csom, append-changes

I am attempting to pull all values using CSOM from a field on a share point site. I think I am closer than I have been but am hung up again. I am getting the exception Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitualizedWxception when I run the below syntax.

What would be the appropriate way to initialize the field so I can return the data for it?

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
{
   ctx.load(listItem.File);
   FileVersionCollection versions = listItem.File.Versions;
   ctx.Load(versions);
   If (listItem.File != null)
   {
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      if (versions != null)
      {
          foreach (FileVersion version in versions)
         {

         }
       }
    }
}
```

If I do a listItem.File; in my immediate window this is where I see the multitude of errors. What am I doing incorrectly?